# Statistical test

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study

Out of 150 peoples  interview ,  108 supported ban law against smoking and the rest 42 peoples not agreed on  ban , Is that statistically sufficient to reach at conclusion of banning smoking?

Comment: Hi sisay and welcome to the site. This sounds like a homerwork question. If so, please add the [`self-study`](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) tag and read its description carefully. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This can be answered by a simple application of the proportion test. The null hypothesis is whether the the proportion of banning smoking is less than 0.5, the alternative hypothesis is that it's at least 0.5. This is a one-tailed test. I think you can work out the test statistics and p-value yourself.